# how to write setup.py for this application structure?

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I have written an application with python (2.7). The structure looks like:

```
kent$  tree myApp
myApp
|-- foo.py
|-- gui
|   |-- g1.py
|   |-- g2.py
|   |-- g3.py
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- icons
|   |-- a.png
|   `-- e.png
|-- logic
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- l1
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- la.py
|   |   `-- lc.py
|   |-- l2
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- ld.py
|   |   `-- lf.py
|   |-- logic1.py
|   |-- logic2.py
|   `-- logic3.py
|-- myApp.py
`-- resources
    |-- x.data
    `-- z.data
```

Now I am about to write a `setup.py` to distribute my application. I am new to this. After reading the py doc and doing some testing. a few questions come up:

1. **how can I (or should I) package my root package (myApp) under `/lib/python/site-package` ?**

   since in my py file, I reference resources/icons by relative path. for example, in `foo.py` there could be `icons/a.png` and in `gui/g1.py` there could be `../icons/e.png` and so on
2. **how can I package `icons` and `resources` directory?**

   It seems that `package_data` and `data_files` won't copy the two directories to right place.
3. **is this the right way?**

   ```
   packages = [''],
   package_dir = {'': ''},
   package_data= {'': ['icons/*.*', 'resources/*.*']},
   ```

   after install, my files will be:

   ```
   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/icons/*.png
   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/resources/*.data
   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gui/...
   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logic/...
   ```
4. **Is there problem of my application structure?**

   should those resources/icons/whatever files go to certain python package, not under the project root? so that in setup.py I can use `package_data` to copy them to right place.

Comment: Have you read http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#developer-s-guide ? The distribute documentation is a little more detailed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no, I haven't read it. thx for the link. I am on my way there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I read the guide. particularly the section Non-Package DataFiles [http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#id17] it mentioned that setuptools will install all non-package-data under ProjectRoot, not like distutils. this is what I want to have. But it didn't say how to install... or I missed something?

Comment: The `pip`, `easy_install` or `zc.buildout` tools install the package for you; then you use the `pkg_resources` module to load your resources wherever they ended up being installed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, problem is the `icons` and `resources` don't belong to any package. they sit at the project/application root, (no `__init__.py`)

Comment: See [Installing additional files](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files); use the `data_files` entry for that. The `setuptools` machinery will include those into the egg too, and the documentation you already found tells you how to load those resources.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thx, I managed it to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
from ez_setup import use_setuptools
use_setuptools()
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="somename",
      version="1.0",
      description="description string",
      long_description="""\
long description
""",
      author="Foo",
      author_email="bar@gmail.com",
      url="http://nowhere.com",
      include_package_data=True,
      license="MIT",
      packages=["gui", "logic"],
      package_dir={
            "gui": "myApp/gui",
            "logic": "myApp/logic",
            },
      classifiers=[
         "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
         "Topic :: Utilities",
         "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License"
      ],
      data_files=[
          ('/path/to/resources', ['resources/x.data', 'resources/y.data']),
          ('/path/to/icons', ['myApp/icons/a.ico', 'myApp/icons/e.ico'])
      ]
      )
```

Comment: you meant the `path/to/icons` I should manually write for example `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myApp-version-py2.7.egg/icons` ?

Comment: it's wherever you have your files. either relative or absolute paths